# Chrome console behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am injecting through console jquery:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');

jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then I am using some jquery command

```
$('.first').position()
document.elementFromPoint(xPosition, yPosition).click();
```

After emulating click page in browser reloading. And than `$('.first')` allways return `[]`; But on the page there are a lot of tags with class 'first'. It seems that console waiting for updating? Or what?

Comment: That's odd behaviour as `position()` returns an object containing the position of the first element in a set, or `undefined`. Never an array. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/korwm03L/. Also, where are `xPosition` and `yPosition` coming from?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it's coming from $('.first').position(). Simple typing coordinates that return from function in xPosition and yPosition by hands.

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict();` will not result in an error ?

Comment: @passion,it's working well.

Comment: @A191919  I run it in my chrome , told me `jQuery` undefined ...   How could this be , it is async I guess .

Comment: It may be the context - are the elements on the page or in an iframe? Also, try using `document.querySelectorAll('.first')` and see what comes back

Answer (score 0):

The appendChild is loading a script element into the DOM, that script tag then goes and downloads the file set to its src property. But this download takes time. It's asynchronous.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

So when you attempt to access jQuery immediately after in your javascript, that file hasn't been downloaded yet. Imagine that the file took an hour to download. You'd need to wait to be notified that the file had finished downloading before using that code. There's a number of ways to think about this, like using an interval to check if the global variable is there, but I think the simplest is just to use an onload event.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
jq.onload = function(){
  //do stuff using jquery
}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```